# How to save a model without sending a signal?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I save a model, such that signals arent sent. (post_save and pre_save)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can do something like this:

use a unique identifier with a filter and then use the update method of the queryset (which does not trigger the signals)

```
user_id = 142187
User.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(name='tom')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
ModelName.objects.bulk_create([your object/objects])
```

also you can read more here [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8077) has been marked as "wontfix" because:

> In short, it sounds like, given the defined purpose of signals, it is
>   the attached signal handler that needs to become more intelligent
>   (like in davedash's suggestion), rather than the code that emits the
>   signal. Disabling signals is just a quick fix that will work when you
>   know exactly what handlers are attached to a signal, and it hides the
>   underlying problem by putting the fix in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8077) pending a Django design decision for this feature.

Included in the ticket is a diff for a patch with the proposed implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mutual relations on models and their signals
still you can decouple signal's logic to have more signals of same type, and handle your logic in more sophisticated way:

You can check in signals, the state of object:

`kwargs['created']`

You can check the state of any pasted extra value:
So in one signal, you will read at first:

```
if `kwargs['instance'].skip_signals`:
   return
```

and in another place, before `save()` you will just set that `skip_signals` on the specific object, in specific situation.
(there is no need to define it as model field)

You can also do not emit signals:

- by overriding method(s) on models,
- or by adding own `save_without_signals()`,
- or just as mentioned already, doing `filter(pk=<>).update(...)`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there still isn't a 'nice' way to do this, but if you're open to exploring hacky solutions, then I'll add one to the mix.

If you look at the django model source code, specifically `save_base()` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.1/django/db/models/base.py#L776) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.1/django/db/models/base.py#L800), you'll see that the `pre_save()` and `post_save()` signals are both wrapped in a conditional:

```py
if not meta.auto_created:
  // Emit signal
```

We can directly manipulate the meta options of a model or instance through the `_meta` [API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/meta/) which means we're able to 'disable' the signals from firing by setting `auto_created = True` on the instance we want to save.

For example:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=(MyModel))
def save_my_model(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # Modify the instance
        instance.task_id = task.task_hash

        # HACK: Prevent `post_save` signal from being called during save
        instance._meta.auto_created = True
        instance.save()
        instance._meta.auto_created = False

    elif instance.has_changed("schedule"):
        # Modify the instance
        instance.task_id = 'abc123'

        # HACK: Prevent `post_save` signal from being called during save
        instance._meta.auto_created = True
        instance.save()
        instance._meta.auto_created = False
```

The major caveat here is that this is undocumented behaviour and it could well change it future releases of django.