# Google Calendar Integration with Django

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Is there a fully fledged Django-based example of a Google Calendar integration? I was reading through [Google's example page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django) but their link at the bottom is outdated.

I'm specifically struggeling with the refresh token as Google's examples focus solely on how to get the access token. That's what I have so far:

```
@staff_member_required
def authorize_access(request):
    return redirect(get_flow(request).step1_get_authorize_url())

@staff_member_required
def oauth2_callback(request):
    credentials = get_flow(request).step2_exchange(request.GET['code'])

    store = get_store()
    store.put(credentials)
    credentials.set_store(store)

    return redirect('...')

def get_flow(request):
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(os.path.join(CREDENTIAL_DIR, CLIENT_SECRET_FILE),
                                      SCOPES,
                                      redirect_uri='%s://%s/google-calendar/oauth2-callback/' % (request.META['wsgi.url_scheme'], request.META['HTTP_HOST'],))
    flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
    flow.params['approval_prompt'] = 'force'

    return flow

def get_store():
    return oauth2client.file.Storage(os.path.join(CREDENTIAL_DIR, ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE))

def has_valid_api_credentials():
    credentials = get_store().get()
    return credentials is not None

def build_service():
    credentials = get_store().get()

    if not credentials:
        return None
    elif credentials.access_token_expired:
        http = credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
        http = get_store().get().authorize(http)
    else:
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    return service

def create_events(rental_request):
    service = build_service()

    event = service.events().insert(...).execute()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a note here: Although the code works, as per https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/7a8641a7f0718c0dce413436f23691e8590face1/docs/index.rst, oauth2client has been deprecated recently in favour of google-auth library - https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/tree/edfe24602051969e32917e82bcedd2bace43e260

You can find the documentation of the new library here - https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

To use the new library, the code can be written as

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

import pytz

from google.oauth2 import service_account

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service_account_email = "app-calendar@xxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('google_calendar_credential.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(SCOPES)


def build_service():
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=scoped_credentials)
    return service


def create_event():
    service = build_service()

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    event = (
        service.events()
        .insert(
            calendarId="primary",
            body={
                "summary": "Foo 2",
                "description": "Bar",
                "start": {"dateTime": start_datetime.isoformat()},
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": (start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()
                },
            },
        )
        .execute()
    )

    print(event)

create_event()
```

As I do not have enough reputation to post this as comment, I am posting this as a separate post

Answer (score 16):

Researching a lot of different approaches I found out that server-to-server authentication is what I wanted. This way no user has to explicitly give permissions and acquired auth-tokens don't have to be renewed. Instead, using a service account, a server can make calls itself.

Before you can start coding, you have to setup such a service account and add it to your calendar that you want the service account to access. Google has written down the three steps to create an account [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#creatinganaccount). Afterwards, go to https://calendar.google.com, locate on the left side of the screen the calendar you want to share with your new service account and click the triangle next to it. From the drop-down menu choose calendar settings. This takes you to a screen where you'll find the calendar-ID which you'll need later (so write it down) and also displays a tab at the top to share access to the calendar. As "person" insert the email address from the service account, give it the respective permissions and **click save** (if you don't click save the service account won't be added).

The code for this is actually pretty elegant:

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import pytz

import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

service_account_email = 'XXX@YYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'creds.p12'

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
scopes = [SCOPES]

def build_service():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        service_account_email=service_account_email,
        filename=CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
        scopes=SCOPES
    )

    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    return service


def create_event():
    service = build_service()

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='<YOUR EMAIL HERE>@gmail.com', body={
        'summary': 'Foo',
        'description': 'Bar',
        'start': {'dateTime': start_datetime.isoformat()},
        'end': {'dateTime': (start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()},
    }).execute()

    print(event)
```

I'm using oauth2client version 2.2.0 (`pip install oauth2client`).

I hope this answer helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Nowadays, google uses JSON key format as default, so your code can be adapted from `credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(service_account_email=service_account_email,
filename=CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,scopes=SCOPES)` to `credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(filename=<The filename of your key in JSON format>,scopes=SCOPES)`

Comment: Is the `from address` same as the `calendarId` value OR the `service_account_email `?
How can I set a specific from address so that person recieving mail can reply to that address rather than the service_account_email?

Comment: @pasql is this viable in 2020?

Comment: Thank you @pasql . Solved problem!

Answer (score 5):

As this post was quite a while ago I wanted to share my 2020 version of it. Thanks for this post. Helped me a lot to achieve my goal.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

import pytz
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

service_account_email = "INSERT_HERE"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    filename="FILENAME.json", scopes=SCOPES
)


def build_service():
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    return service


def create_event():
    service = build_service()

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    event = (
        service.events()
        .insert(
            calendarId="CALENDARID@group.calendar.google.com",
            body={
                "summary": "Foo",
                "description": "Bar",
                "start": {"dateTime": start_datetime.isoformat()},
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": (start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()
                },
            },
        )
        .execute()
    )

    print(event)

create_event()
```

Comment: can you specify what is exactly `CALENDARID` here and how can we get this.

Comment: @sumit4613 go to https://calendar.google.com, locate on the left side of the screen the calendar you want to share with your new service account and click the triangle next to it. From the drop-down menu choose calendar settings. This takes you to a screen where you'll find the calendar-ID

Answer (score 4):

## 2022

credits to @joey Coder(i would have added this as comment but its too long)

If you want your website or app to make events or calendars without have to use the Google accounts of the users you should use service accounts.

In https://console.cloud.google.com/ choose your project or start new one.

In the navigation menu choose "APIs & Services"
enable new APIs and then look up "calendar API", enable the API

Under "APIs & Services">"Credentials", select "Create Credentials" and click on "service account", fill in the desired name, and continue. Set role as owner(or other desired)(owner gives full access you you might want to switch to something less powerful). Click "Done"

This will redirect you to the credentials page.
Under the "Service accounts" click on the desired account(this will redirect you to the IAM & Admin panel)
Under the tab "Keys" click "ADD KEY" and select json, this will download a json file to your computer.

in the Calendar page in google
get and add the calendar ID to the admin panel under AgendaClients "CalendarId"
add the service account to the people shared as admin (make changes to events)

This is how it looks like in my django project:

## signals.py

```
import datetime
import json
import os

from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from .models import  Event

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]


def get_service(refresh=False):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
        json.loads(os.environ.get("client_secret")), scopes=SCOPES
    )
    # or if you have a file
    # credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    #     filename="file.json", scopes=SCOPES
    # )
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    return service


def handle_event(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
        """this function creates the events in the google agenda and updates them if changed in the website"""
        service = get_service()
        event = instance
        if not event.end_date:
            event.end_date = event.start_date
        if not event.end_time and event.start_time:
            event.end_time = event.start_time
        elif not event.end_time:
            event.end_time = datetime.datetime.min.time()
        if not event.start_time:
            event.start_time = datetime.datetime.min.time()
        if event.end_date < event.start_date:
            event.end_date, event.start_date = event.start_date, event.end_date
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(
            id=event.id
        )  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555060/how-to-save-a-model-without-sending-a-signal
        # this is used so that we can update the google event within this signal without reshooting this signal(signals shot every time an object is saved)
        event = {
            "summary": event.description,
            "location": event.location or "",
            "description": (event.description + " " + event.summary),
            "start": {
                "dateTime": datetime.datetime.combine(
                    event.start_date, event.start_time
                ).isoformat(),
                "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": datetime.datetime.combine(
                    event.end_date, event.end_time
                ).isoformat(),
                "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
            },
            "recurrence": [],
            "reminders": {},
        }

        if created or not instance.google_link:
            try:
                event = (
                    service.events()
                    .insert(
                        calendarId=os.environ.get("calendarId"),
                        body=event,
                    )
                    .execute()
                )
                queryset.update(google_link=event["id"])
            except HttpError as error:
                # print("An error occurred: %s" % error)
                pass
        else:
            try:
                event = (
                    service.events()
                    .update(
                        calendarId=os.environ.get("calendarId"),
                        body=event,
                        eventId=instance.google_link,
                    )
                    .execute()
                )
                queryset.update(google_link=event["id"])
            except HttpError as error:
                # print("An error occurred: %s" % error)
                pass
        # print("#############ADDED NEW       #############")


def delete_event(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """this function deletes an event from google agenda when deleted in the website"""
    try:
        service = get_service()
        service.events().delete(
            calendarId=os.environ.get("CalendarId"),
            eventId=instance.google_link,
        ).execute()
    except:
        pass


post_save.connect(handle_event, sender=Event)
post_delete.connect(delete_event, sender=Event)
```

## models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    google_link = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    # google link is used to edit events in google if you change them in your website
```

Feel free to ask any questions or point out anything

Comment: i have used your method and created event,but it wont show it calendar,and when i print upcomming calendars using the api it shows all the event i created using above and also when i open the event link it shows a google server error page with error code 500.You know any fix

Comment: I have generated a github repo with working instructions for you to be able to do this with service accounts. maybe that helps https://github.com/gmadurov/Django-google-calendar

Comment: Thank you posting the github link.I have solved my issue by not using service accounts