# Google calendar API integration with Python - Change sender's mail address in Calendar API

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to figure out the Google API integration with Python(Django) to send calendar events to the users. While everything is running fine but the emails are being sent from my google's service account mail address which is in the form:

```
<project_name>-django@<project_name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

which is coming from `client_email` attribute of my json file.
Please read this answer for implementation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37933674/3520404

Now, I want all the mails to be sent from a specific mail address so that people can reply to the mails.

Here is my code:

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def get_google_calendar_service():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        filename=settings.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    )

    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    return service


def create_event():
    service = get_google_calendar_service()

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='<MY_EMAIL_ID>', body={
        'summary': 'Foo',
        'description': 'Bar',
        'start': {'dateTime': start_datetime.isoformat()},
        'end': {'dateTime': (start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()},
    }).execute()

    print(event)
```

I want to send all the calendar invite mails from `<MY_EMAIL_ID>` but that's not happening. Is there anyway to control the `FROM EMAIL ADDRESS` while sending the calendar invite mails? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the serviceaccount is the account creating the events. You do have several options though.

1) If you have a G Suite account, use domain wide delegation on the serviceaccount, and impersonate the `<MY_EMAIL_ID>` you want to use. It has to be in the G Suite domain of course. [This example](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object) is for the Admin SDK, but it's still the best example of impersonation. The line `credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)` is the one of interest.

2) No G Suite account, then you need to use the OAuth2 loginflow to get OAuth2 credentials for `<MY_EMAIL_ID>`, and then use these credentials to authenticate the request. [Extensive documentation is available](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).