# implementing oauth2 for google calendar api with django

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Can anybody direct me to a complete example of implementing oauth2 with django?
From the older posts, I found some bits and pieces, or work-arounds, but I am not yet experienced enough to put the pieces together.
I want to integrate into an web app creating, updating, deleting events.

Followed the quickstart in the documentation, it works fine.

The quickstart is made for a desktop app, I need to use it in a web app. Here I got stuck, on authorizing the app and on receiving the approval of the resource owners to access their calendars.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: What do you mean by switching to web app flow? Have you checked this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754999/google-calendar-integration-with-django)?

Comment: the quickstart shows how to implement the authorizaton for a desktop application. This is a snippet from it ' flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)'. I generated the credentials for a web app, so I should also change this part, since the generated credentials json file doesn not contain the same info. I did check the post you mention, it suggest using a service account, to avoid requesting permissions from the resource owners, but I do want to ask for permission to use their calendars

Comment: How about this one, have you checked [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) which explains how to use oauth in your web application that will prompt a user for consent

Comment: I have checked the documentation, I understand the principle, but the example is with flask, I am working with django. This is my first project, so probably my understanding of thing is not quite there yet. Would have been nice to have a tutorial, there are quite a lot out there on simpler topics. I will give another try to the link above, see if I can finally  succeed. Thanks

Comment: This [Github repository](https://github.com/dev0088/django-oauth-react-admin-dashboard) and [this one](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-React-GoogleOauth2-Example) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: does this answer help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74866141/10108726