# Google Calendar API v3 error after allowing permission using oauth2.0

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I followed the [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python) to integrate my django app with google calendar. The difference from quickstart to my situation is that i just want to generate a URL and send it back to my user, through

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(f"{PATH_TO_FILE}/{CLIENT_SECRET_FILE}", SCOPES)
(auth_url, state) = flow.authorization_url()
if is_dev():
    auth_url += '&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A43759%2F'
print(auth_url)
```

(OBS: I added this is_dev option, because no redirect_uri was not considered)

I get this printed URL and get this steps:

**1- The URL from auth_url printed when i ran the program**

[image]

**2- After choosing my user**

[image]

**3- and BAM, I cant proceed (i am redirected to localhost:47759 and cant access)**

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting your issue by accessing the link on your **screenshot error** `localhost:43759/?state=7hrsPUBkkgDUvmDaCGo0gQGYv5gvJW&code=4/0AWgavdcxmbQlowustMWIef7FSILOlnKhhuce 1x62Z7k6kRBPLA6GCDBbLEp9ziaCQQKsFg&sc` to an **incognito window**? This seems like your current network is blocking the localhost on a regular browser window.

Comment: hey, that is not the problem, somehow i can't access this url.. I might have found a solution that I can post

Comment: I see, you may want to post it as an answer to your question so other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we wen't through one solution, that 3 steps are important to talk about.

1- Create a new credential on Google Cloud, OAuth 2.0 Client ID for Web Application, as js origins with my local url, and another redirect URL authorized (this redirect solved the number 3 error for the question)
[image]

2- Also I read some examples about, and to get the user authorization, we send him an URL, if everything goes ok, he is redirected to our endpoint described above

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(f"{PATH_TO_FILE}/{CLIENT_SECRET_FILE}", SCOPES)
flow.redirect_uri = URL_SAVED_ON_STEP_1
(auth_url, state) = flow.authorization_url()
print(auth_url)
```

3- And to the URL receiving my code, was necessary an endpoint where we could save the user credential and use it if we wanted to add an event on the user calendar

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(f"{CONFIG_FILES_PATH}/{CLIENT_SECRET_FILE}", SCOPES)
flow.redirect_uri = URL_SAVED_ON_STEP_1
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)
creds = flow.credentials
with open(f"{CONFIG_FILES_PATH}/token.json", 'w') as token:
    token.write(creds.to_json())
```

So we can let any user share their calendar and we can manage as they allow