# How do I prevent post_save signals from triggering from a nested foreign key field?

Tags: django, django-signals

Django model is sending two post_save signals and I can't figure out how to handle them.

I want to trigger a single post_save signal on the save of an instance that has a foreign key field that is also being saved at the same time.

This solution: [How to save a model without sending a signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555060/how-to-save-a-model-without-sending-a-signal) seems close to home but my foreign key field must be an entirely new instance which means the update method won't work.

Here's my model

```
event = Event(
                start_date=template_fields['start_date'],
                end_date=template_fields['end_date'],
                event_title=f'Stock Count Reminder',
                description=f'Stock reminder count on auto scheduling',
                event_type=template_fields['event_type']
            )
event.save()
stock_tempalate.schedule_time = event
stock_tempalate.created_by = info.context.user
stock_tempalate.unique = True
stock_tempalate.save()
```

I want only stock_template.save() to trigger the post_save signal and not event.save()

Here is my signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StockCountTemplate)
def start_job(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if 'created' in kwargs:
        if not kwargs['created'] and instance.unique:
            start_schedule_templates()
```

Putting a debugger in the signal's callback shows that I am receiving two signals. The first one doesn't have field values for the stock_templates while the second one does.

Doing a print(kwargs) inside the callback prints the following:

The first trigger:

```
{'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x10d00fc50>, 'created': True, 'update_fields': None, 'raw': False, 'using': 'default'}
[]
```

And the second trigger which is what I am intrested in:

```
{'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x10d00fc50>, 'created': False, 'update_fields': None, 'raw': False, 'using': 'default'}
[1]
```

Is there a way to disable the first signal?